# cannot configure HDFS address using gethue/hue docker image

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs, hue

I'm trying to get the Hue docker image from gethue/hue, but it seems to ignore the configuration I give him and always look for HDFS on localhost instead of the docker container I ask him to look for.

Here is some context:

1. I'm using the following docker compose to launch a HDFS cluster:

```
 hdfs-namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:1.1.0-hadoop2.7.1-java8
    hostname: namenode
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=davidov
    ports:
      - "8020:8020"
      - "50070:50070"
    volumes:
      - ./data/hdfs/namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env


  hdfs-datanode1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:1.1.0-hadoop2.7.1-java8
    depends_on:
      - hdfs-namenode
    links:
      - hdfs-namenode:namenode
    volumes:
      - ./data/hdfs/datanode1:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
```

This launches images from BigDataEurope, which are already properly configured, including:

```
- the activation of webhdfs (in /etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml):
  - dfs.webhdfs.enabled set to true
- the hue proxy user (in /etc/hadoop/core-site.xml): 
  - hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts set to *
  - hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups set to *
```

The, I launch hue following their [instructions](http://gethue.com/getting-started-with-hue-in-2-minutes-with-docker/):

First, I launch a bash prompt inside the docker container:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gethue/hue:latest bash
```

Then, I modify desktop/conf/pseudo-distributed.ini to point to the correct hadoop "node" (in my case a docker container with the address 172.30.0.2:

```
[hadoop]

  # Configuration for HDFS NameNode
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[hdfs_clusters]]
    # HA support by using HttpFs

    [[[default]]]
      # Enter the filesystem uri
      fs_defaultfs=hdfs://172.30.0.2:8020

      # NameNode logical name.
      ## logical_name=

      # Use WebHdfs/HttpFs as the communication mechanism.
      # Domain should be the NameNode or HttpFs host.
      # Default port is 14000 for HttpFs.
      ## webhdfs_url=http://172.30.0.2:50070/webhdfs/v1

      # Change this if your HDFS cluster is Kerberos-secured
      ## security_enabled=false

      # In secure mode (HTTPS), if SSL certificates from YARN Rest APIs
      # have to be verified against certificate authority
      ## ssl_cert_ca_verify=True
```

And then I launch hue using the following command (still inside the hue container):

```
./build/env/bin/hue runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8888
```

I then point my browser to localhost:8888, create a new user ('hdfs' in my case), and launch the HDFS file browser module. I then get the following error message:

```
Cannot access: /user/hdfs/.
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=50070): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/hdfs?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hue&doas=hdfs (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address',))
```

The interesting bit is that **it still tries to connect to *localhost*** (which of course cannot work), even though I modified its config file to point to 172.30.0.2.

Googling the issue, I found another config file: desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini. I tried modifying this one and launching hue again, but same result.

Does any one know how I could correctly configure hue in my case?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Laurent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your one-off `docker run` command is not on the same network as the docker-compose containers.

You would need something like this, replacing `[projectname]` with the folder you started `docker-compose up` in

```
docker run -ti -p 8888:8888 --network="[projectname]_default" gethue/hue bash
```

I would suggest using Docker Compose also for the Hue container and volume mount for a INI files under `desktop/conf/` that you can specify simply

```
fs_defaultfs=hdfs://namenode:8020
```

(since you put `hostname: namenode` in the compose file)

You'll also need to uncomment the WebHDFS line for your changes to take affect

All INI files are merged in the `conf` folder for Hue

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It makes me understand a bit more docker networks. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue (or I missed sth). While it allowed me to ping 172.30.0.1 from within the hue container (which was not possible without linking to the same network, I checked), it still gives me the same message (still trying to reach localhost). I really have the feeling that I'm not modifying the right ini file. But how can I check which ini file is loaded and that therefore my config has been taken into consideration? Or maybe I also need to modify another option in that ini file?

Comment: The pseudo distributed ini file is correct. You left `webhdfs_url` property commented out, so it's the default. As mentioned, though, using a volume mount would make more sense than starting the container to just the shell, then editing the file. You lose all your changes doing that

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed forgetting to uncomment the webhdfs_url. Included it in the docker-compose, but had to also add the a links option to have it recognize the namenode. Thanks a lot!