# Hue access to HDFS: bypass default hue.ini?

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, hdfs, hue

## The set up

I am trying to compose a lightweight minimal hadoop stack with the images provided by [bde2020](https://hub.docker.com/u/bde2020) (learning purpose). Right now, the stack includes (among others)

- a namenode
- a datanote
- hue

Basically, I started from Big Data Europe [official docker compose](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), and added a hue image based on [their documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/bde2020/hdfs-filebrowser)

## The issue

Hue's file browser can't access HDFS:

```
Cannot access: /user/dav. The HDFS REST service is not available. Note: you are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser, "hdfs" or part of HDFS supergroup, "supergroup".

HTTPConnectionPool(host='namenode', port=50070): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/dav?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hue&doas=dav (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8119a3cf10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

## What I tried so far to delimit the issue

- to explicitly putted all the services on the same network
- to point dfs_webhdfs_url to `localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1` in the namenode env file ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48845801/cannot-configure-hdfs-address-using-gethue-hue-docker-image)) and edit `hue.ini` in hue's container accordingly (by adding `webhdfs_url=http://namenode:9870/webhdfs/v1`)

when I log into hue's container, I can see that namenode's port 9870 is open (`nmap -p 9870 namenode`). 50070 is not. I don't think that my issue is network related. Despite editing `hue.ini`, Hue still go for port 50070. So, **how can I force hue to go for port 9870** in my current setup? (if this is the reason)

## docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    hostname: namenode
    domainname: hadoop
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - ./entrypoints/namenode/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
      - .env
    networks:
      - hadoop_net
    # TODO adduser --ingroup hadoop dav

  datanode1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    hostname: datanode1
    domainname: hadoop
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop_net

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop_net

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop_net    

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop_net

  filebrowser: 
    container_name: hue
    image: bde2020/hdfs-filebrowser:3.11
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    volumes: # BYPASS DEFAULT webhdfs url
      - ./overrides/hue/hue.ini:/opt/hue/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini
    environment:
      - NAMENODE_HOST=namenode
    networks:
      - hadoop_net

networks:
  hadoop_net: 

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to review http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/, especially part about enabling webhdfs in NameNode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, found it. A few key elements:

- in hadoop 3.*, webhdfs no longer listen to 50070 but 9870 is the standard port
- overriding `hue.ini` involves to mount a file named `hue-overrides.ini`
- the hue image from gethue is more up to date than the one from bde2020 (their hadoop stack rocks, though)

## Docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 8020:8020
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
      - ./overrides/namenode/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
      - .env
    networks:
      - hadoop

  filebrowser: 
    container_name: hue
    image: gethue/hue:4.4.0
    ports:
      - "8000:8888"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    volumes: # HERE
      - ./overrides/hue/hue-overrides.ini:/usr/share/hue/desktop/conf/hue-overrides.ini
    depends_on:
      - namenode
    networks:
      - hadoop
      - frontend

  datanode1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: datanode1
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode1:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode1:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop    

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.1.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode1:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop

networks:
  hadoop: 
  frontend:

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
```

## hadoop.env

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts=*
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups=*
CORE_CONF_io_compression_codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

HDFS_CONF_dfs_replication=1
HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true
HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled=false
HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_datanode_registration_ip___hostname___check=false
```

## hue-overrides.ini

```
[desktop]
  http_host=0.0.0.0
  http_port=8888
  time_zone=France
  dev=true
  app_blacklist=impala,zookeeper,oozie,hbase,security,search
[hadoop]
  [[hdfs_clusters]]
    [[[default]]]
      fs_defaultfs=hdfs://namenode:8020
      webhdfs_url=http://namenode:9870/webhdfs/v1
      security_enabled=false
```

Thanks @cricket_007

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the namenode service, you also mounted an `.env` file. Did you put any information in there which might be important for me to reproduce your environment?

Comment: I tried commenting out the `.env` file in the namenode volume and ran `docker-compose up` and got the following error `ERROR: for namenode  Cannot start service namenode: OCI runtime create failed:...mounting \\\"/home/kevinsuedmersen/dev/hadoop/overrides/namenode/entrypoint.sh\\\...Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type...` So I'm missing this `./overrides/namenode/entrypoint.sh` file on my host. Could you provide this and other files which might be necessary for me to reproduce your environment?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the Filebrowser working with this INI

```
[desktop]
  http_host=0.0.0.0
  http_port=8888
  time_zone=America/Chicago
  dev=true
  app_blacklist=impala,zookeeper,oozie,hbase,security,search
[hadoop]
  [[hdfs_clusters]]
    [[[default]]]
      fs_defaultfs=hdfs://namenode:8020
      webhdfs_url=http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1
      security_enabled=false
```

And this compose

```
version: "2"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:1.1.0-hadoop2.7.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    ports:
      - 8020:8020
      - 50070:50070
      # - 59050:59050
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop

  datanode1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:1.1.0-hadoop2.7.1-java8
    container_name: datanode1
    ports:
      - 50075:50075
      # - 50010:50010
      # - 50020:50020
    depends_on:
      - namenode
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode1:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
    networks:
      - hadoop

  hue:
    image: gethue/hue
    container_name: hue
    ports:
      - 8000:8888
    depends_on:
      - namenode
    volumes:
      - ./conf/hue.ini:/hue/desktop/conf/pseudo-distributed.ini
    networks:
      - hadoop
      - frontend

    volumes:
      hadoop_namenode:
      hadoop_datanode1:

    networks:
      hadoop:
      frontend:
```

`hadoop.env` has to add hue as a proxy user as well

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user=root

CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts=*
CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups=*

HDFS_CONF_dfs_replication=1
HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true
HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled=false
```

Comment: thanks, your insights helped me (gethue is definitely better than the one of bde2020) but you're `docker-compose` does not work: I can't reach Hue's interface :/. I am one step closer, though

Comment: maybe I did not understand the *proxy user part*. I added these lines in my `hadoop.env`. Am I supposed to replace the * with an actual user name and group from the namenode?

Comment: The star means to impersonate all users and groups. Regarding the interface, I believe it did work at one point